# Transformation from EPSG:31983 to EPSG:4326 change only one axis (R + ggmap)

Tags: coordinate-system, r, ggmap

I'm trying to convert my shapefile with `spTransform()`, but it's not successful. I don't know why it's changing only one axis. I want to change the axis into *decimal degrees*.

```
# Libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggsn)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(grid)
library(plyr)    

URL <- "https://osm2.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?filename=public.galapagos_islands&q=select+*+from+public.galapagos_islands&format=geojson&bounds=&api_key="
fil <- "gal.json"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)
gal <- readOGR(fil, "OGRGeoJSON")
topo <- readOGR("public.geojson.json", layer ="OGRGeoJSON")
```

so here if you change CRS("+init=epsg:31983"), it's working, but I don't know why it's not working with only 4326...

```
gal <- gSimplify(gUnaryUnion(spTransform(gal, CRS("+init=epsg:4326")), id=NULL), tol=0.001)
topo <- spTransform(topo, CRS("+init=epsg:4326")) # epsg:4326 is decimal degree, epsg:31983 is meters only

# double check that they match
identical(proj4string(topo),proj4string(gal))    ## [1] TRUE
gal_map <- fortify(gal)
topo_map <- fortify(topo)
topo_map <- join(topo_map, topo@data, by="id")
names(topo_map)

# Complete Galápagos Island!!!! -------------------------------------------
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=gal_map, 
                    data=gal_map,
                    aes(x=long, 
                        y=lat, 
                        map_id=id),
                    color="black", 
                    fill="#8FBC8F", #comment# #FFFFFF is white, # the colour #8FBC8F is a standard green for map's background
                    alpha = 0.4,
                    size= .1) # was .5 
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + ggsn:::scalebar(gal_map, # scale bar 
                           dist=50, 
                           location="bottomleft", 
                           st.size=5)
gg <- gg + #theme_map() + # veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy sober
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12, 
                                   colour = "black", 
                                   angle = 0),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=12),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(.2, "cm"), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "blue",linetype = "dotted",size = .1),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), # lightsteelblue2 for water # remove the default grey, you can add blue color for water (# background making illusion that this is water)
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), # remove grid
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # remove grid
        strip.background = element_blank(), # remove grid
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", # border to the map
                                    fill=NA, 
                                    size=1)) 
gg <- gg + geom_path(data = topo_map, # adding the elevation line
                     aes(long, lat, group=group, colour = elev), 
                     size = 0.1 , 
                     alpha=0.4, 
                     linetype = 1) + 
#         geom_polygon(data = topo_map, # adding the elevation polygon
#                      alpha=0.01,
#                      aes(long,
#                          lat, 
#                          fill=elev, 
#                          group=group)) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = "aquamarine", # guide = "none" if you don't want
                       high = "darkgreen", 
                       guide = "colourbar") + 
  labs(title = "Galápagos Islands", 
       y = "lat", 
       x = "long", 
       colour = "Elevation") 
gg
```

[image]

In the end, I want that the axis are shown in decimal degrees. Not in meters (31983). I don't want to do this manually (by writing the axis myself), I want to transform the scale.

Comment: maybe you should try something like spTransform(topo, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ")" or could you include in your post the output of proj4string(topo) and proj4string(gal)

Comment: I've tried something like this: `gal <- gSimplify(gUnaryUnion(spTransform(gal, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ")), id=NULL), tol=0.001)
topo <- spTransform(topo, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ")) # epsg:4326 is decimal degree, epsg:31983 is meters only`, but it's still not working...

Comment: `proj4string(gal)
"+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"`

`proj4string(topo)
"+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"`

Comment: Galápagos Island are west of South America, not Africa!

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new with that kind of EPSG. If I understand correctly, it's not the right coordinate reference system. I just want to change the coordinate system to put it in decimal degree. But I want the Galápagos to be shown. Where could I find this information?

Comment: you can take a look at this website: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/

Comment: Yes, I know this website, but I don't get it. It's suppose to change automatically the value of the x & y axis. Right? Why it's only changing y axis? What should I modify, the towgs 84 argument?

Comment: you just need to find the right espg for your region. just browse in the website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36923/discussion-between-m-beausoleil-and-mlavoie).

Comment: When I look at the json file, the coordinates are already in lat/lon (degrees) AKA EPSG:4326. If you want to change the coordinates to a projected CRS, try 32615 or 32715.

Comment: I did this, but my axis are not in decimal degree. Do you know what I would do to my code?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect something went wrong with your geojson. You should not need to reproject at all.

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

URL <- "https://osm2.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?filename=public.galapagos_islands&q=select+*+from+public.galapagos_islands&format=geojson&bounds=&api_key="
fil <- "gal.json"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)
gal <- readOGR(fil, "OGRGeoJSON")

# this is in EPSG 4326
proj4string(gal)
> [1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

gal_map <- fortify(gal)
ggplot() + 
  geom_map(map=gal_map,data=gal_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id)) + 
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: So the problem was the scale at the bottom. Thanks for your help! I figure it out with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scalar function.

Should be:

```
ggsn:::scalebar(gal_map, # scale bar 
                           dist=50, 
                           location="bottomleft", 
                           model = "WGS84", 
                           dd2km = TRUE,
                           st.size=5)
```

Full code

```
# Libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggsn)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(grid)
library(plyr)    

URL <- "https://osm2.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?filename=public.galapagos_islands&q=select+*+from+public.galapagos_islands&format=geojson&bounds=&api_key="
fil <- "gal.json"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)
gal <- readOGR(fil, "OGRGeoJSON")
topo <- readOGR("public.geojson.json", layer ="OGRGeoJSON")
topo <- spTransform(topo, proj4string(gal))

# double check that they match
identical(proj4string(topo),proj4string(gal))    ## [1] TRUE
gal_map <- fortify(gal)
topo_map <- fortify(topo)
topo_map <- join(topo_map, topo@data, by="id")
names(topo_map)

# Complete Galápagos Island!!!! -------------------------------------------
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=gal_map, 
                    data=gal_map,
                    aes(x=long, 
                        y=lat, 
                        map_id=id),
                    color="black", 
                    fill="#8FBC8F", #comment# #FFFFFF is white, # the colour #8FBC8F is a standard green for map's background
                    alpha = 0.4,
                    size= .1) # was .5 
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + ggsn:::scalebar(gal_map, # scale bar 
                           dist=50, 
                           location="bottomleft", 
                           model = "WGS84", 
                           dd2km = TRUE,
                           st.size=5)
gg <- gg + #theme_map() + # veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy sober
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12, 
                                   colour = "black", 
                                   angle = 0),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=12),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(.2, "cm"), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "blue",linetype = "dotted",size = .1),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), # lightsteelblue2 for water # remove the default grey, you can add blue color for water (# background making illusion that this is water)
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), # remove grid
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # remove grid
        strip.background = element_blank(), # remove grid
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", # border to the map
                                    fill=NA, 
                                    size=1)) 
gg <- gg + geom_path(data = topo_map, # adding the elevation line
                     aes(long, lat, group=group, colour = elev), 
                     size = 0.1 , 
                     alpha=0.4, 
                     linetype = 1) + 
#         geom_polygon(data = topo_map, # adding the elevation polygon
#                      alpha=0.01,
#                      aes(long,
#                          lat, 
#                          fill=elev, 
#                          group=group)) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = "aquamarine", # guide = "none" if you don't want
                       high = "darkgreen", 
                       guide = "colourbar") + 
  labs(title = "Galápagos Islands", 
       y = "lat", 
       x = "long", 
       colour = "Elevation") 
gg
```